# Why is there a gap between UIButtons in my app on iPhone and not in the simulator?

Tags: ios5, uikit, uibutton

I'm making an app that uses a keypad composed of UIButtons.

When the keypad is mocked up in Photoshop and then cut up to form the separate buttons, they are completely congruous when the view is composed in storyboard in Xcode 4.3.

Likewise, when I run the app in iPhone Simulator, the UI is perfect:
[image: iPhone Simulator]

However, when I run the app on an actual iPhone (iOS 5.1), I notice slight horizontal gaps between some of the buttons.
[image: iPhone]

I'm at a loss to explain this. I've even checked the storyboard XML manually to ensure that all dimensions are correct and that the x,y positioning coordinates are appropriate.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? TIA.

Comment: If this is what u wanna use... y not use num keypad already provided by Apple. Tht will be easier to implement as well

Comment: I'm using the UIButtons to update a UILabel rather than a text field. Also, I don't think the number keyboard has a Call button?

Comment: Fist column of buttons seems ok. You could copy y values of first column to second and third column and output should look ok.

Comment: Check your UIButton Style in storyboard i think it is the issue. It should be Custom.